# Generating unique number in LibreOffice Calc

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

So I have a document that allows a user to select a site/department from a dropdown list. Each site/Department has a unique extension prefix e.g. 10, 11, 12, 13, etc. When a user selects the desired Site/Departments, I get the extension prefix using VLOOKUP depending on the users selection. What I now need to do is append 2 more digits to the extension prefix to create a 4 digit extension. So the output would be something like 1001, or 1002, but each extension needs to be unique. So I could generate a random number between 00-99, but how do I make sure that the generated number is not equal to any other number generated for that site? Different sites/departments can have the same generated number, because they'll have a different prefix.

Any ideas on how to solve this? I find myself in a pickle.

Comment: Do you have in one sheet multiple Dropdowns (with same department list)?

Comment: The department dropdowns are all on the same page. They get their options from a different page though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to count up only until the current row with `COUNTIF`.
So the **Range** is from the *first row* to the *current row* with the **value** of the **current row**.

Setup:

```
#DepN  #DepId #Empty #DepDropdown =VLOOKUP =COUNTIF =TEXT =CONCATENATE
Foo    10            Lorem         12      1        01    1201
Bar    11            Foo           10      1        01    1001
Lorem  12            Dolor         13      1        01    1301
Dolor  13            Foo           10      2        02    1002
                     Foo           10      3        03    1003
                     Bar           11      1        01    1101
```

All Columns Formula:

```
VLOOKUP:     =VLOOKUP(D2-D7;$A$2:$B$5;2;0)      // D2 in the first row up to D7 in the last
COUNTIF:     =COUNTIF($E$2:E2-E7;E2-E7)
TEXT:        =TEXT(F2-F7;"00")
CONCATENATE: =CONCATENATE(E2-E7;G2-G7)
```

For example is the first COUNTIF-Entry: `=COUNTIF($E$2:E2;E2)`, the second one is `=COUNTIF($E$2:E3:E3)`

`DepN`and `DepId` is the constant "database" with all the departments. (I guess these columns should be hidden)

The `DepDropdown` is the Column with all departments each cell.

Of curse you can chain these 4 formulas and put them together in one column.